# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository Class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

While adding Oauth2 configurations to my project, I got this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.AuthenticatedPrincipalOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoader$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
```

For reference: [Blog Link](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2021/05/05/client-credentials-spring-security#create-a-webclient-based-application)

I have these dependencies in my maven project.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</parent>

...
    <!-- Spring Boot Web starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Security Starter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Oauth2 client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- WebClient -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong here? I think the problem is related to dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue, solved by downgrading spring-security-oauth2-client to 5.8.2

error text:

`Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2ClientConfiguration$OAuth2ClientWebMvcSecurityConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'setAuthorizedClientRepository' parameter 0;`